# I magnetised a USB cable - could it damage my PC or laptop

Tags: usb

I honestly don't know which S.E site to ask this on. If this is wrong, could some kind moderator please migrate it? Thanks.

I have a reasonably strong magnet, which I use to magnetize screwdrivers, to make it easier to pick up & hold screws.

I just noticed that it had become attached to a USB 3 cable.

Ought I to throw the cable away? Could it damage my laptop, PC, external harddrive, etc,  if I plug it in?

Comment: No; The charge is weak enough it will disapate over time

Comment: I wonder why this merited a down vote, when it received several good answer. As usual, we will never know, as the downvoter was not prepared to explain, which wolul have helped me, and others, to ask better qustions in future. Way to build acommunity

Comment: Whenever downvoters bother explaining they just get attacked by a slew of insults and feigned consternation anyway

Comment: I see. Personally I have always explained on the few occassions when I have downvoted.  This get pretty bad on S.O, with drive-by "me too" downvoters. If a post atrracts one downvote, it will attract ten more within twenty minutes. I get the feeling than many downvoters have not read the question, as I see many resonable quesitons with multiple downvotes. Sigh! C'est la vie </rant>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the reason we have metal covers over our computers :) .  Actually, your vacuum cleaner or other big motors would cause more problems to your PC than a casually magnetized cable.  If you had an old deguasser or library book demagnetizer, that might cause problems, but you should be fine.

Comment: So (+1), if I use that cable to connect my laptop & external hardrive & either of them fritzes, you will buy me a replacement? :-)

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking if the magnetism itself will cause an issue - no. There should be nothing in immediate proximity to the port that is sensitive enough to be damaged.  Given the relatively thin metal involved and the fact that it is going to be carrying current when plugged in, the magnetic properties should dissipate.

If you are asking - is it possible the magnetized cable will pickup bits of magnetic trash and possibly result in you shoving stuff into your ports and possibly creating an issue - then yes that's possible.  Say your magnetized cable is on your desk and a spent staple get sucked into it without you knowing and you plug that into a port - may not be a happy thing.

To be safe, try and demagnetize it and keep it clean.